# How do I make a pseudo element fit the entire width of div? It is cutting off at the scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, width, pseudo-element

Can someone help me figure out how to make my pseudo element span the entire width of my div element, instead of cutting off at the scroll please?

I've tried a few different things found online including changing display type, width etc. Please keep in mind this needs to be displayed horizontally. If you have any other suggestions how to make this work or any improvements in general that would be great.

thanks

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Vardana';
}
.container {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(20,30,48,.9), rgba(36,59,85,.9));
 margin: 20px;
 height: 400px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 overflow: scroll;
 font-size: 13px;

}
.container ul {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr;
 position: relative;
}

.container ul:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 4px;
 background: white;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.Event1:before {
 content: "";
 margin-top: -28px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(20,30,48,.8), rgba(36,59,85,.2));
 border: 1.5px solid white;
}
.Event2:before {
 content: "";
 margin-top: -28px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(20,30,48,.8), rgba(36,59,85,.2));
 border: 1.5px solid white;
}
.Event3:before {
 content: "";
 margin-top: -28px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(20,30,48,.8), rgba(36,59,85,.2));
 border: 1.5px solid white;
}
.Event4:before {
 content: "";
 margin-top: -28px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(20,30,48,.8), rgba(36,59,85,.2));
 border: 1.5px solid white;
}
.Event5:before {
 content: "";
 margin-top: -28px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(20,30,48,.8), rgba(36,59,85,.2));
 border: 1.5px solid white;
}
.Event6:before {
 content: "";
 margin-top: -28px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(20,30,48,.8), rgba(36,59,85,.2));
 border: 1.5px solid white;
}
li {
 list-style: none;
}

.Event1 h4 {
 color: #feb645;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.Event2 h4 {
 color: #feb645;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.Event3 h4 {
 color: #feb645;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.Event4 h4 {
 color: #feb645;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.Event5 h4 {
 color: #feb645;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.Event6 h4 {
 color: #feb645;
 font-size: 14px;
}
.Event1 {
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;
}
.Event2 {
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;
}
.Event3 {
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;
}
.Event4 {
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;
}
.Event5 {
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;
}
.Event6 {
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: white;
 width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang=“en”>
  <head>
 <title>Dads Website</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="JavaScript.js" defer> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
          <h1>History Timeline</h1>
    </header>

  <div class="container">
      <ul id="timelineList">
        <li class="Event1"><h4>Event 1</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
          aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
          ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </li>
        <li class="Event2"><h4>Event 2</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
          aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
          ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </li>
        <li class="Event3"><h4>Event 3</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
          aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
          ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </li>
        <li class="Event4"><h4>Event 4</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
          aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
          ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </li>
        <li class="Event5"><h4>Event 5</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
          aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
          ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </li>
        <li class="Event6"><h4>Event 6</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
          aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
          ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </li>
      </ul>

  </div>
  </body>

  <footer class="footer">
  </footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve changed from grid to inline-block to make this still display horizontally. But I think the below worked for me...
Width: max-content;